# Play sound when iPhone sound switch is on silent mode in xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I want to play video with full sound, even i have the sound switch(positioned above volume buttons) set to silent mode. ***What i did is working on iOS 7.x and 8.1.x but doesn't work on 8.2.*** It's quite weird, not really sure. How to go about it. Any sample code will be appreciated.

**I don't want to change to AVPlayer,at this stage, as i am almost ready for release**

Here's what i have already tried and works in 7.x and 8.1.x

```
//I declare a class level variable
MPMusicPlayerController VolumeRocker;

//initialize it
VolumeRocker =  MPMusicPlayerController.ApplicationMusicPlayer;

//Use it. I set this inside the click even of button
//which i use to start playback of video

VolumeRocker.Volume = 1f;
```

Am i missing something ? This works in following scenarios in 7.x and 8.1.x,(but doesn't work on iOS 8.2, not sure abt 8.3)

1) I switch to silent mode and start playing the video. I get to see the volume popup and i can hear the sound

2) I set the volume to zero with sound switch set to ringer mode, i play the video , i get the volume popup. I can hear the sound, then i switch the sound mode to silent using the switch, i can still hear the sound. ***Even if i keep toggling the modes using the switch, it doesn't affect the volume of the video(which is what i need).***

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your audio session by setting the Category property:

http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=P%3aAudioToolbox.AudioSession.Category

An explanation of the possible values and how to control them are available here:

http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aAudioToolbox.AudioSessionCategory